# negative number to ASCII conversion

Tags: java, string, numbers, ascii

How I can convert negative number into ASCII value?

I have to convert **-1 ** into **ASCII** value.

That means:

```
 inputbyte[] = 0
 output[] = -1
```

I did replacement like:

```
replacement 0 to -1 in string.
```

But I cant treat -1 as a number after represent string into Byte[]. I have to handle -1 as a single number like in integer.

Actually My original problem is:

```
input = "0110110111001000";
output should be = "-111-111-1111-1-11-1-1-1";
```

after that, I should be able to treat -1 and 1 as numbers i.e Byte.

How can I do that?
thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are you basically trying to do a string replace and change any "0" to "-1"?

Comment: @mike yes, replacement of 0 to -1. But after replacement i cant great -1 as a one byte[].

Comment: `-1` isn't a byte.  A byte is between `0` and `255`.  The string "-1" would be two bytes.

Comment: Converting a negative number to ASCII (the way you showed it in your example) doesn't make sense to me. Isn't it better to use [2's compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)?

Comment: @MikeChristensen: In Java, the ranges of the `byte` type is from -128 to 127, because it is a signed 8-bit value. (But that still doesn't make the question any easier to understand.)

Comment: @GregHewgill - Ah, sorry I'm more of a C# guy.  Oh and `wcCODE` of course :)

Comment: how, i can handle string "-1" as integer number?

Comment: Would '\xff' be the char you are looking for? -1 is all bits set in twos complement numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I have to convert -1 ** into **ASCII value.
```

-1(signed char) equals to 127(unsigned char or ASCII value)

127 is DEL code in ASCII table.

To get an int from string:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf("-1");
                             |
                             |
                             here you put your sub-string of "-1"
```

Strring replacement:

```
String str="010100100011100011";
String result = str.replaceAll("0", "-1");
```

Big-integer to string:

```
String str=my_big_integer.toString();
```

Comment: Are you using wrapper types or primitive types for you integers?

Comment: The number 10011111 is a big integer, i have to convert all zeros into -1. finally i have to add two big integer for get result. 
i have to treat all the byte individually.

Comment: Ok, i put the big-integer to string conversion and string-replacment.

Comment: yes, after replacement it seems necessary to consider -1 as two bytes. I will try for best. :)